# value from a JavaScript form

Tags: javascript

I'm building a form that allows to calculate the Bishop Score: https://jsfiddle.net/molecoder/1oqxsw81/ .

The user is allowed to select between 4 options and each of these options (0 cm, 1-2 cm, ...) have an associated value.

Here is the *HTML* code for the form:

```
<form action="" id="bishopform" onsubmit="return true;">
     <div>
         <fieldset>
            <legend>Bishop score</legend>
            <p>(modify one field to see the score)</p>
            <div id="bishopScore"></div>
            <label><b>Cervical Dilatation</b></label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcervicaldilatation" value="cerdi1" onclick="calculateTotalBishop()"/>0 cm</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcervicaldilatation" value="cerdi2" onclick="calculateTotalBishop()" checked/>1-2 cm</label><br/>
             <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcervicaldilatation" value="cerdi3" onclick="calculateTotalBishop()" />3-4 cm</label><br/>
             <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcervicaldilatation" value="cerdi4" onclick="calculateTotalBishop()"/>5-6 cm</label><br/>
              <br/>
           </fieldset>
      </div>
</form>
```

Here is the *JavaScript* code to process the selection:

```
 var cervical_dilatation = new Array();
 cervical_dilatation["cerdi1"]=0;
 cervical_dilatation["cerdi2"]=1;
 cervical_dilatation["cerdi3"]=2;
 cervical_dilatation["cerdi4"]=3;

 // getCervicalDilation() finds the points based on the answer to "Cervical Dilation".
// Here, we need to take user's the selection from radio button selection
function getCervicalDilation()
{  
    var cerdiPoints=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="bishopform"
    var theForm = document.forms["bishopform"];
    //Get a reference to the answer the user Chooses name=selectedcervicaldilatation":
    var selectedCervicalDilation = theForm.elements["selectedcervicaldilatation"];
    //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedCervicalDilation.length = 4
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedCervicalDilation.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedCervicalDilation[i].checked)
        {
            //we set cerdiPoints to the value of the selected radio button
            cerdiPoints = cervical_dilatation[selectedCervicalDilation[i].value];
            //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
            //No reason to continue if we get a match
            break;
        }
    }
    //We return the cerdiPoints
    return cerdiPoints;
}

function calculateTotalBishop()
{
    //Here we get the Bishop Score by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var bishopScore = 3*getCervicalDilation() + 1;

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('bishopScore');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = bishopScore+"% likelihood that induction will be successful";

}
```

For any particular reason, I'm not able to see the result of user's selection.

**How can this be fixed?**

Comment: Why are you using an Array, but treat it is an object.

Comment: it was adapted from here: http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because of the how the **JSFiddle** handles their scripts in the preview. Because they inject the entered script into iframe by using `window.onload` method, your functions become **private** in the new scope, and can't be called from html.

Your code works expected as it is in the fiddle from SO:

```js
var cervical_dilatation = new Array();
 cervical_dilatation["cerdi1"]=0;
 cervical_dilatation["cerdi2"]=1;
 cervical_dilatation["cerdi3"]=2;
 cervical_dilatation["cerdi4"]=3;

 // getCervicalDilation() finds the points based on the answer to "Cervical Dilation".
// Here, we need to take user's the selection from radio button selection
function getCervicalDilation()
{  
    var cerdiPoints=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="bishopform"
    var theForm = document.forms["bishopform"];
    //Get a reference to the answer the user Chooses name=selectedcervicaldilatation":
    var selectedCervicalDilation = theForm.elements["selectedcervicaldilatation"];
    //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedCervicalDilation.length = 4
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedCervicalDilation.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedCervicalDilation[i].checked)
        {
            //we set cerdiPoints to the value of the selected radio button
            cerdiPoints = cervical_dilatation[selectedCervicalDilation[i].value];
            //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
            //No reason to continue if we get a match
            break;
        }
    }
    //We return the cerdiPoints
    return cerdiPoints;
}

function calculateTotalBishop()
{
    //Here we get the Bishop Score by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var bishopScore = 3*getCervicalDilation() + 1;

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('bishopScore');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = bishopScore+"% likelihood that induction will be successful";

}
```

```css
#bishopScore{
            padding:10px;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:limegreen;
    }
```

```html
    <form action="" id="bishopform" onsubmit="return true;">
         <div>
             <fieldset>
                <legend>Bishop score</legend>
                <p>(modify one field to see the score)</p>
                <div id="bishopScore"></div>
                <label><b>Cervical Dilatation</b></label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcervicaldilatation" value="cerdi1" onclick="calculateTotalBishop()"/>0 cm</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcervicaldilatation" value="cerdi2" onclick="calculateTotalBishop()" checked/>1-2 cm</label><br/>
                 <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcervicaldilatation" value="cerdi3" onclick="calculateTotalBishop()" />3-4 cm</label><br/>
                 <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcervicaldilatation" value="cerdi4" onclick="calculateTotalBishop()"/>5-6 cm</label><br/>
                  <br/>
               </fieldset>
          </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `calculateTotalBishop()` has to be a global function... But jsfiddle wraps your code in `window.onload`... And that's the reason an error is logged which says `Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateTotalBishop is not defined`

To fix this just change the "Load Type" in js settings in jsfiddle from "onLoad" to "No wrap - in body"... That will solve the problem

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1oqxsw81/1/

PS:
It's recommended to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in js instead of `onclick` in html
and it'll be much better if you use `onchange` event because the value can be changed from a keyboard also